# Pass JSON to javascript in JSP

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jsp

I've got following page, where I'm trying to pass JSON, that I've recieved from DB, to javascript area. If I declare simple variable, like

```
String var = "123";
```

then it can be passed without problems. But I'm unable to pass my JSON to javascript in the same page. 
May be it's due to double quotes in my JSON.

Here is my page:

```
    <%@ page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%@ page import="com.google.gson.*"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.*"%>
<%
    Connection dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(
            "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/redmine", "postgres", "123456");
    Statement getFromDb = dbConnection.createStatement();
    ResultSet employees = getFromDb.executeQuery("select * from \n" 
                                                 + "(select us_gr.group_id as id, us.lastname||us.firstname as text, -1 as parentid, 1 as ord\n" 
                                                  + "from   users us,\n"
                                                  + "groups_users us_gr\n"
                                                  + "where us.id = us_gr.group_id\n"
                                                    + "UNION\n"
                                                + "select us_gr.user_id as id, us.lastname||' '||us.firstname as text, us_gr.group_id as parentid, 2 as ord\n"
                                                + "from     users us,\n"
                                                + "groups_users us_gr\n"
                                                + "where us.id = us_gr.user_id) x \n"
                                                + "order by ord\n");
    JsonArray recordsArray = new JsonArray();
    while (employees.next()) {
        JsonObject currentRecord = new JsonObject();
        currentRecord.add("id",
                new JsonPrimitive(employees.getString("id")));
        currentRecord.add("text",
                new JsonPrimitive(employees.getString("text")));
        currentRecord.add("parentid",
                new JsonPrimitive(employees.getString("parentid")));
        recordsArray.add(currentRecord);
    }
    //out.print(recordsArray);
    //out.flush();
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();      
    if (recordsArray != null) { 
    int len = recordsArray.size();
    for (int i=0;i<len;i++){ 
    list.add(recordsArray.get(i).toString());
   } 
}

//out.print(list);
String testvar = "qwerty";
String testvar1 = recordsArray.toString();
//out.print(testvar); //shows JSON well
%>
<script type="text/javascript">
var testvar="<%out.print(testvar);%>"; 
var testvar1="<%out.print(testvar1);%>";
//var jsvariable1 ="<%out.print(recordsArray.size());%>";
document.write(testvar); //works
document.write(testvar1); //doesn't work
</script>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "pass my JSON to javascript in the same page"?

Comment: Yes that could be a double quote problem because you are dumping out the json into a string.  You could just make it an object right away, by omitting the quotes, ie `var testvar1=<%out.print(testvar1);%>;` - should work!

Comment: Yep! That works, thank you.     
    var testvar1=<%out.print(testvar1);%>;
    testvar1 = JSON.stringify(testvar1);